# Inverse image of a function in multivariable calculus?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inverse

Let $f: R^2 \rightarrow R^2 $ defined by $f(x,y) = (x+y,xy).$

Claim : Inverse image of each point in $R^2$ under f has at most two elements.

My Claim :

Suppose $f(x,y) = (x+y,xy)= (p,q).$ We have to find suitable x and y.

By solving the equations I get,

$x = \dfrac {p \pm \sqrt{p^2 - 4q}}{2q}, y = p-\dfrac {p \pm \sqrt{p^2 - 4q}}{2q}.$

My doubt is that for those $(p,q)$ such that $p^2 < 4q .$ Inverses doesn't exist.

How come inverse exist for all point in $R^2$ ?

Comment: There is no guarantee that f(x,y) is surjective.

Comment: Since $(x-y)^2\ge0$ then $x^2-2xy+y^2\ge0$ so $x^2+2xy+y^2\ge4xy$. Thus it is always the case that $p^2\ge4q$.

Comment: "at most two" means none, one or two. So you have already solved it. The question is not about inverse function, it is about inverse image.

Comment: You have a mistake in your solution for $x$ and $y$. There should be no factor of $q$ in the denominators. $x$ and $y$ are conjugates of each other.

Answer (score 1):

They don't. For example, if $p = 0, q = 1$ then $x + y = p = 0$ implies $x = -y$ but then $xy = -x^2 = q = 1$ has no solution.

Comment: Probably, inverse function from the Image Space might be possible I guess.

Comment: Well, the function is not one-to-one so...

Comment: Can you find those point violating 1-1 condition ?

Comment: @RisingStar it can't be 1-1 if the inverse image has 2 elements,  find points that violate the 1-1 condition?  f(1,2) = f(2,1)

Answer (score 0):

Given $(p,q)\in{\mathbb R}^2$ you are interested in the set of all pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying $x+y=p$, $xy=q$. By Vieta's theorem $\{x,y\}$ then is the solution set of the quadratic equation $$t^2-pt+q=0\ .\tag{1}$$ Therefore we can say the following: If $p^2-4q>0$ then $(1)$ has two different real solutions $t_1$, $t_2$, giving rise to the two pairs $(t_1,t_2)$ and $(t_2,t_1)$. It follows that $\#f^{-1}(p,q)=2$ in this case. If $p^2-4q=0$ then $(1)$ has one real solution $t_0$, giving rise to the single pair $(t_0,t_0)$. It follows that $\#f^{-1}(p,q)=1$ in this case. If $p^2-4q<0$ then $f^{-1}(p,q)=\emptyset$.